# Distributional assumption for a VAR model: is normality needed?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, assumptions, vector-autoregression

Do all variables in a VAR (Vector Autoregressive model) need to be normally distributed? Or there is no restriction about the distributions of the variables in this model (normal or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the case of vanilla regression, the distributional assumptions are usually formulated for the error term rather than for the variables themselves. (You could formulate equivalent distributional assumptions on the conditional distribution of the response given the regressors, given the additional assumptions of linearity and correct specification of the model).

Again, similarly to the case of vanilla regression, different assumptions are needed for ensuring different properties of different estimators. E.g. for obtaining consistency and asymptotic normality of OLS estimators of model parameters (regression coefficients), it is enough that errors are i.i.d. For finite sample normality of the OLS estimators, normality of errors is needed as an additional assumption.

Comment: I wonder if the last part (regarding finite sample properties) is actually as simple in VAR as in the linear regression. My guess is yes, which is in my answer, but I am not sure.